# Perl load module BEGIN

Tags: perl

I have this code

```
print "Starting\n";
BEGIN {
        $module='Data::Dumper';
        $module_available=1;
        eval "use $module; 1" or $module_available = 0;
        }
$var=1;
print "Module=$module_available\n";
print Dumper $var if ($module_available==1);
```

and the output is

```
Starting
Module=1
$VAR1 = 1;
```

---

and this

```
print "Starting\n";
        $module='Data::Dumper';
        $module_available=1;
        eval "use $module; 1" or $module_available = 0;
$var=1;
print "Module=$module_available\n";
print Dumper $var if ($module_available==1);
```

and the output

```
Starting
Module=1
```

---

Why on the first scenario the variable is printed

Answer (score 6):

You should always

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

In your second example, when your code is compiled, `Dumper` is not known as a function. So perl treats it as a bareword filehandle. If you use warnings, you get

```
print() on unopened filehandle Dumper at file.pl line 10.
```

In the first example you wrap the eval in a BEGIN block. So `Dumper`is already imported when the line of its usage gets compiled.

You can read more about BEGIN blocks here: [perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END)

Comment: Worth noting that adding parentheses to `Dumper($var)` will allow Perl to recognize it as being a function call, eliminating the need for the `BEGIN` block.